# Stop Excel from converting text in cell to scientific notation

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my attempts to remove the spaces from the cell `"71646E 10 0"` I get `"5.58E+104"` when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. There are about 100 cells for me to fix. I can do them one at a time by editing each cell and deleting the space.

Is there a function that can to this all at once?

Comment: If simply you are trying to remove the White spaces, then applying Scientific notation is never a good idea ,  and could you write the original value since 71646E 10 0 is not just a number !!

Comment: I guess they are non-printable characters, you may try this `=TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(160)," ")))`

Comment: This answer to similar question worked best for me Excel 2016: ["Text to Columns" trick](https://superuser.com/a/632066/750636)

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track, the simple solution is to remove scientific notation from displaying is to highlight the column, select custom format and enter just a zero (0) in the Type.

Comment: It's 2021 and this bug still exists in Excel. Your suggestion worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**New Answer**

So my original answer of being clever with a Custom Format doesn't actually work.

However it seems you can simply format the cells to Text, then remove the spaces and all Excel will do is complain (with little green triangles on every cell where you do this) that there's a number stored in Text.

**Old Answer**

My go-to for this is to just slam a Custom Format on the cells I want to have show exactly what is in them.

[image: Customer Number format]

It's pretty dirty, but it does the trick and can be applied to whole selections at a time.

Answer (score 2):

With data like:

[image]

run this short VBA macro:

```
Sub RemoveSpaces()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = "'" & Replace(r.Value, " ", "")
    Next r
End Sub
```

to produce:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*In attempts to remove the spaces from the cell, you can try this simple equation:*

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B64," ","")
```

[image]

**Note,** adjust cell references in formula as needed.