# Facing issue with Mobile number while i save my excel sheet to csv format

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, csv

I`m using excel 2010. I have mobile number field in one of my columns, for example: 919810236547. After completing my work, i convert my excel sheet to csv (comma delimited) format.  Then, when i try to open the csv sheet in excel, the mobile number is displayed as 9.19810E+11.
Can you help me with a solution? slightly urgent sir. Thank You

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The duplicate tells you why this is happening, and https://superuser.com/a/786859/19943 tells you specifically what to do to fix it.

Comment: Hello sir, im using microsoft excel 2010. I have name and mobile numbers fields in my excel sheet. When i save the excel sheet to csv format (comma delimited) and then open my csv sheet in excel the mobile numbers appears improper i.e. 9.19810E+11. I want the mobile number to appear correctly, i.e. 919810236547 . Hope im able to explain you what you need. Thanks

Comment: You can't use CSV for what you want. It does not include information on column types and formats so you would have to set up per the link I gave every time you reimport the file.