# Excel always shows scientific values after opening the file

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to have normal values instead of scientific in Excel. The problem is, that after applying the following solutions:

1. Right-click-> Format cells -> Number -> decimals 0
2. Concatenate(A1)
3. =""&A1

the Excel still keeps opening my file with scientific values

[image]

Is there any smart solution, which could be applied here?

[Why does Excel treat long numeric strings as scientific notation even after changing cell format to text](https://superuser.com/questions/413226/why-does-excel-treat-long-numeric-strings-as-scientific-notation-even-after-chan)

https://www.techguy.org/threads/solved-why-do-numbers-show-up-as-6-34479e-11-in-excel.625748/

https://best-excel-tutorial.com/59-tips-and-tricks/188-disable-scientific-notation

Comment: Is the file you are opening actually an XLSX or does it happen to be a CSV?

Comment: Do you mean, you can apply any of solutions 1,2 or 3, which temporarily fixes the problem, but when you save, close and reopen, the formatting changes back to scientific? This should only be the case if the file is saved as CSV (which doesn't save Excel's advanced formatting). Saving as XLSX should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, I save my file as the .csv

Comment: Is it possible to use TRIM function?